# Non-rectangular crop Phaser.Sprite or Phaser.Image

Tags: image, phaser-framework

I have an image already preloaded in Phaser.State:

```
game.load.image(name, url);
```

I would like to use it in two different scenarios:

1. As image (rendered in full-size without any cropping)
2. As sprite source (rendered partially, cropped by hex)

First scenario is simple, but I can't find solution for second one. `Phaser.Sprite.crop` applies only `Phaser.Rectangle` and I can't put `Phaser.Polygon` into this method. How can I solve this problem?

PS: Of course, I don't want to download second (cropped) version of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use alpha mask like [here](http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=bitmapdata&f=alpha%20mask.js&t=alpha%20mask)

But in this case you need upload an image of mask (your polygon).